# AWS VPN network limit to 500 Mbps

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc

I tried to copy data from AWS to my office. The tunnel is VPN (OpenVPN).
I can see I am limited to 500 Mbps, although the inter-office VPNs is 1 Gbps. 
Did anyone else noticed something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using VPC VPN or an EC2 instance running OpenVPN on the AWS-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used their VPN a while ago and had some network limits as well, I can't remember if it was 500 Mbps or lower than that.

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned in [AWS Direct Connect FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/faqs/)

> 1Gbps and 10Gbps ports are available.Speeds of 50Mbps, 100Mbps, 200Mbps, 300Mbps, 400Mbps, and **500Mbps** can be ordered from any APN partners supporting AWS Direct Connect. Read more about APN Partners supporting AWS Direct Connect.

Answer (score 0):

the XEN hypervisor of EC2 instances has a limit of 550 mbit/s for ipsec traffic. Switch to a SSL hased vpn to get about 1500 mbit/s